# django-taggit-autocomplete and south

Tags: django, django-south, django-taggit

I use django-taggit-autocomplete, but when doing a schememigrating, I got an error

```
 ! Cannot freeze field 'main.hotels.tags'
 ! (this field has class taggit_autocomplete_modified.managers.TaggableManagerAutocomplete)
 ! Cannot freeze field 'main.rooms.tags'
 ! (this field has class taggit_autocomplete_modified.managers.TaggableManagerAutocomplete)

 ! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
 ! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
 ! models parser (it often broke things).
 ! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
```

So I search a little bit and found django-taggit-autocomplete-modified, which should solve the problem, but it doesn't.

What is the best way how to workaround it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem adding following code to models.py

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_ignored_fields
add_ignored_fields(["^taggit_autocomplete\.managers"])
```

Comment: If this is your correct answer, It's better to choose it as _Correct Answer_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some context to @Douglish's own answer - taken from [South's documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html#field-name-patterns):

> you can ignore some fields completely if you know they’re not needed.
>   For example, django-taggit has a manager that actually shows up as a
>   fake field (this makes the API for using it much nicer, but confuses
>   South to no end). The django-taggit module we ship with contains this
>   rule to ignore it:
>
> ```
> from south.modelsinspector import add_ignored_fields
> add_ignored_fields(["^taggit\.managers"])
> ```

Comment: Please add some content from the link.